# render QChartView with high resolution

Tags: c++, qt, rendering, qtcharts

I want to save a QChartView as a .png image. Therefore I use the following code:

```
QChartView *chartView = qobject_cast<QChartView*>(/* get chart view */);

QImage image;
QPainter painter(&image);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
chartView->render(&painter);
image.save("test.png");
```

When I look at the `test.png` image the resolution is quite bad.

Can I somehow say, that the QChartView should be rendered with a fixed resolution like 150dpi or a fixed size like (500x700 pixels)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale your image by using [`QPaintDevice::devicePixelRatioF()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintdevice.html#devicePixelRatioF) and using a `QPixmap` instead of an image.

```
const auto dpr = chartView->devicePixelRatioF();
QPixmap buffer(chartView->width() * dpr, chartView->height() * dpr);
buffer.setDevicePixelRatio(dpr);
buffer.fill(Qt::transparent);

QPainter *paint = new QPainter(&buffer);
paint->setPen(*(new QColor(255,34,255,255)));
chartView->render(paint);
```

Once the image is scaled to the proper resolution, you can convert it to a `QImage` or save it directly:

```
QFile file("image.png");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
uffer.save(&file, "PNG");
```

Comment: `chartView->render(&buffer);` gives the following error message: `error: no matching function for call to ‘QtCharts::QChartView::render(QPixmap*)’
     chartView->render(&buffer);`

Comment: Ups, the proper interface expects a QPainter instead of a QPixmap, you can allways use a QPainter to draw on a QPixmap.